# Is there any downtime for Azure app service assosiated with docker image update?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

We utilizing Azure app services with linux os and we deploying containerized .net core application to the service.
The deployment runs using Set-AzWebApp function from Az.Websites ps module. One of the parameters passed to the function is containerimagename which provides a new container version to the service. There is a separate CI process that builds the docker image and pushes it into ACR.
When the Set-AzWebApp runs as a part of release pipeline and the new container is deployed I couldn't see any downtime to the service, meaning running health check endpoint returns 200 in browser and the service seems to be available all the time. But my test is unreliable in a sense that I am just pinging health check which is very simple endpoint that exercises service middleware only without running data base request or some other logic.

According to my understanding the service needs to recycle itself to accept a new version of the image and the question is would the consumer of the service expirience any downtime during the recycle, also what happens with requests that run during recycle process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The continuous deployment feature of the Azure App Service will help you avoid downtime when you update the image. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#to-prevent-down-time-when-you-update-your-code-use-continuous-deploymentapplies-to-web-app-for-containers) you can see the details:

> We'll pull the image and start the container, and we'll wait until
> that new container is running and ready for HTTP requests before we
> switch over to it. During that time, your old image will continue to
> serve requests into your app.

So maybe you enable this feature.